# Recreating Activity causes infinite loop

Tags: android

I am trying to change the theme of my app, so I call the following methods when the user presses a button:

```
activity.setTheme(R.style.BlueTheme);
activity.recreate();
```

However, whenever this happens, the app goes into an infinite loop with the console output being:

```
02-01 11:36:15.077 9245-9276/org.example.androidscouting E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab7d5680
02-01 11:36:15.131 9245-9276/org.example.androidscouting W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-01 11:36:15.131 9245-9276/org.example.androidscouting W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa3170780, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

And the above just loops forever until I manually close the app.

Could anyone tell me what the issue is and how to fix it, or at least point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Additional code

On Create:

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Utils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scouting);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLinear);
    l.requestFocus();

    //createTheApp();

    Switch colorSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.team_color);
    colorSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);


}
```

onCheckedChange():

```
    @Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked){
        Utils.changeToTheme(this,Utils.THEME_RED);

    } else {
        Utils.changeToTheme(this, Utils.THEME_BLUE);
    }
}
```

Utils.java - Adapted from another quetion

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Utils
{
    private static int sTheme = 2;
    public final static int THEME_RED = 1;
    public final static int THEME_BLUE = 2;

    public static void changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme)
    {
        sTheme = theme;
        activity.recreate();
    }
    /** Set the theme of the activity, according to the configuration. */
    public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity)
    {
        switch (sTheme)
        {
            default:
            case THEME_BLUE:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.BlueTheme);
                break;
            case THEME_RED:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.RedTheme);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


<style name="BlueTheme" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorBluePrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorBluePrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorBlueAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="RedTheme" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorRedPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorRedPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorRedAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I think we need to see more code.

Comment: Added more code, let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Add some debug to `onCheckedChanged()`, make sure it's not calling that  when it's not supposed to. i.e. `Log.d("check_changed", "check changed");` or `System.out.println("check_changed");`

Comment: I would put a breakpoint on the line `activity.recreate();` and run your app in a debugger. I suspect something during the creation of the activity is changing the value of the switch which causes your listener to recreate the activity which causes the value to change which causes your listener to recreate the activity ...

Comment: Thank you Andrew! Yours and Anshul's answer let me solve the problem, I needed to move the setState() call before the setChangeStateListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in this method

```
     @Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked){
        Utils.changeToTheme(this,Utils.THEME_RED);
        //Assign isChecked = false;

    } else {
        Utils.changeToTheme(this, Utils.THEME_BLUE);
        // Assign isChecked = true;
    }
}
```